# Installing libxml2 on secure Debian box

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I have a very stripped Debian distro on a small custom computer that I purchased (don't know much about this distro as it was recommended on some site). The name is 'sid' and runs 2.6.37.1 kernel. Unfortunately it doesn't have any PPA's in the sources.list file so I cannot apt-get any software. I am trying to get libxml2 (Gnome package) for a program called xmllint.

Since I cannot apt-get this software I need to get each debian package. Going further it needs:

libxml2 depends > multiarch (the computer is i586 not i386) > libc > libc-dev > ... and so on until infinity.

This distro has the build-essentials installed but I can't instal libc and libc-dev alone as it leads to 100's of more dependencies.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: Populate `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the correct entries (adding a Debian mirror should be sufficient) and let `apt-get update && apt-get install libxml2` do it's magic.

Comment: Used: http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ to get a Debian ppa. Thanks!

Comment: It's great that you could solve the problem with Marco's suggestion, because it's obviously the best solution, when possible, but if you really did not have access to apt online, you could use [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) to avoid hunting for dependencies.

Comment: PPA is an Ubuntu term, not a Debian term.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The OP probably meant populating the sources.list with a valid mirror. Even on Ubuntu you don't put PPAs in the sources.list. Debian supports PPAs if you know the compatibility implications: `add-apt-repository ppa:<repository-name>`

Comment: @Marco Sure, I understand the OP meant valid deb/deb-src sources. My point was just that he was using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a mirror from [the list of mirrors](http://mirror.debian.org/status.html) or run `netselect-apt` and add valid mirror to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Example:

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian unstable main
```

Then run an `apt-get update` to update the package list, followed by

```
apt-get install libxml2
```

to install `libxml2` including dependencies.